# Stuck on bootloop how to pull files using adb(rooted)

Tags: adb

My samsung galaxy note 3 is stuck on bootloop(stuck on logo with sparkels animation),went into recovery mode and tried to pull mp3 files from downloads i get a message remote file does not exist,i cant pull any file i get the same message!is there a way to get the data ?
Root-Cwm- based recovery v6.0.5.0
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGy6j.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error above for a couple of different reasons.

1. You are spelling the directories incorrectly
2. ADB pull is used for pulling specific file names.

Assuming adb can actually access the devices while its stuck in a boot loop (you could test this by running 'adb devices' and see if you receive a response.

What you need to do is run the following command to list all the files in your "downloads folder"

```
adb shell ls -r /sdcard/download
```

Every file in your downloads folder will be listed. You can then do the following the pull the files

```
adb pull /sdcard/download/filename.mp3
```